# Почему не работает второй метод в Controller

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Каждый раз по вызывании второго метода передается html без стилей . Можете сказать это с чем связано .Погуглил но нечего не нашел по этой теме.

```
<а href="/index/">Page</a>
<а href="/index/hello/">Page</a>
```

При ссылке `<а href="/index/hello/">Page</a>`  подключается сраница но без стилей. Помогите найти проблему .

Структура сайта

```
project
---------model
---------view
         ----------index.php
---------controller
         ----------IndexController.php
         ----------ErrorController.php
---------config
         ----------router.php
---------template
         -----------style.css
         -----------script.js
         images
---------.htaccess
---------index.php
```

view/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php $hello; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

controller/IndexController.php

```
 class IndexController
 {
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once("view/index.php");
    }

    function actionHello()
    {
        $hello = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

config/router.php

```
class Router 
{


    private $url;


    public function render()
    {

        if (isset($_GET["url"])) 
        {
            $this->url = rtrim($_GET["url"]);
            $this->url = explode("/" , $_GET["url"]);
            $className = ucfirst($this->url[0])."Controller";
            $controllerFile = "controller/" .$className .".php";
            print_r($url);

            if (file_exists($controllerFile)) 
            {
                require_once($controllerFile);
            }
            else
            {
                if(!file_exists($controllerFile))
                {   
                    require_once("controller/ErrorController.php");
                    $controller = new ErrorController();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $object = new $className;
            if (isset($this->url[1])) 
            {  
                $actionName = "action".ucfirst($this->url[1]);
                $object->$actionName();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

template/style.css стили не работают

```
 *{box-sizing:border-box;}
  body
  {
      font-size:100%;
      font-weight:normal;
  }

  body >h1{color:red;}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

project/index.php

```
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    require_once("config/Router.php");

    $router = new Router();
    $router->render();
```

Comment: покажите как роутер работает

Comment: Слишком мало информации, с этим кодом вы не получите ответ

Comment: а покажите ваш html страницу page

Comment: а зачем Вы внизу class Controller вызываете $controller = new Controller();
$controller->actionCategory(); он же должен автоматически вызываться?

Comment: Просто забыл удалить Dmitriy

Comment: Html  показывает без стилей  только разметку

Comment: я думаю что у вас проблема с относительными путями. строка `<link rel="stylesheet" href="template/style.css">` берет файл не от корня сайта а от текущего адреса. т.е у вас должно получится `http://domain.com/template/style.css` а получается `http://domain.com/index/hello/template/style.css` что не совсем соответствует реальности. попробуйте поставить слэш `/` перед путем к файлу стилей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ  сработало